# Cassandra composite - Querying partial columns

Tags: cassandra, composite-key, astyanax

**For the data stored as DynamicCompositeColumns (Long,UTF8) as shown below,**

```
rowkey: t1
column1: 1456394880000:test1:a1, value=...
column2: 1457273146000:test1:a3, value=....
column3: 1457273146000:test2:a3, value=...
```

**1.How to get all columns which matches the column's  2nd component value (Ex. test1) irrespective of 1st component value.**

**The following equality comparison didn't work.**

```
    startComposite.addComponent(Long.MINVALUE, LongSerializer.get(), Operator.Equals));
    startComposite.addComponent("test1", StringSerializer.get(), Operator.Equals));

    endComposite.addComponent(Long.MAXVALUE, LongSerializer.get(), Operator.GreaterEquals)); 
    endComposite.addComponent("test1", StringSerializer.get(), Operator.GreaterEquals));
```

**2. How to get a particular column which matches component2 & component3 values (Ex. test1 & a3)**

```
    startComposite.addComponent(Long.MINVALUE, LongSerializer.get(), Operator.Equals));
    startComposite.addComponent("test1", StringSerializer.get(), Operator.Equals));
    startComposite.addComponent("a3", StringSerializer.get(), Operator.Equals));

    endComposite.addComponent(Long.MAXVALUE, LongSerializer.get(), Operator.GreaterEquals)); 
    endComposite.addComponent("test1", StringSerializer.get(), Operator.EQUALS));
    endComposite.addComponent("a3", StringSerializer.get(), Operator.GreaterEquals));
```